# Group all duplicates as single value in new array

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find only duplicates from a users input and group into a new array with a single value for the duplicates.

ex: [1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5] to [3,4,5]

right now it groups the duplicates = 2, but I need it to group all duplicates > 1.

This is what I have so far.

```js
$('#group').on('click', function() {
  var addFieldsArray = $('.add').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();
  var groupSimiliar = addFieldsArray.sort();

  var groupDuplicates = []
  for (var i = 0; i < groupSimiliar.length - 1; i++) {
    if (groupSimiliar[i + 1] == groupSimiliar[i]) {
      groupDuplicates.push(groupSimiliar[i]);
    }
  }
  console.log(groupDuplicates);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="add" id="one">
<input type="text" class="add" id="two">
<input type="text" class="add" id="three">
<input type="text" class="add" id="four">
<br/>
<input type="text" class="add" id="five">
<input type="text" class="add" id="six">
<input type="text" class="add" id="seven">
<input type="text" class="add" id="eight">
<br/>
<button id="group">Group</button>
```

Comment: Are duplicates necessarily successive?

Comment: @AlixEisenhardt They are after he does `addFieldsArray.sort()`

Comment: Good point, they shouldn't have to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an the keys of an object rather than an array to hold the duplicates, since objects can't have duplicate keys.

```js
$('#group').on('click', function() {
  var addFieldsArray = $('.add').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();
  var groupSimiliar = addFieldsArray.sort();

  var groupDuplicates = {}
  for (var i = 0; i < groupSimiliar.length - 1; i++) {
    if (groupSimiliar[i + 1] == groupSimiliar[i]) {
      groupDuplicates[groupSimiliar[i]] = true;
    }
  }
  console.log(Object.keys(groupDuplicates));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="add" id="one">
<input type="text" class="add" id="two">
<input type="text" class="add" id="three">
<input type="text" class="add" id="four">
<br/>
<input type="text" class="add" id="five">
<input type="text" class="add" id="six">
<input type="text" class="add" id="seven">
<input type="text" class="add" id="eight">
<br/>
<button id="group">Group</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `jQuery.unique()` on your final array, for example (in your code), use it while logging like this:

```
console.log($.unique(groupDuplicates));
```

Or create a new variable before using it:

```
var uniqueGroupDuplicates = $.unique(groupDuplicates);
console.log(uniqueGroupDuplicates);
```

Check the snippet:

```js
$('#group').on('click', function() {
  var addFieldsArray = $('.add').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();
  var groupSimiliar = addFieldsArray.sort();

  var groupDuplicates = []
  for (var i = 0; i < groupSimiliar.length - 1; i++) {
    if (groupSimiliar[i + 1] == groupSimiliar[i]) {
      groupDuplicates.push(groupSimiliar[i]);
    }
  }
  console.log($.unique(groupDuplicates));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="add" id="one">
<input type="text" class="add" id="two">
<input type="text" class="add" id="three">
<input type="text" class="add" id="four">
<br/>
<input type="text" class="add" id="five">
<input type="text" class="add" id="six">
<input type="text" class="add" id="seven">
<input type="text" class="add" id="eight">
<br/>
<button id="group">Group</button>
```